# ng-file-upload Times out after exactly 120 seconds

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I'm trying to send a file but it keeps timing out after 120 seconds.  API team mentions they have a much longer timeout on calls.  I'm trying to see if this is a global angular setting or something else I'm missing.

```
    $scope.uploadRequest = Upload.upload({
          url: '/upload',
          data: {'file':file},
          timeout: 190000 // = 3.16 minutes
      })
```

Comment: have you tried testing the upload functionality with a simple upload form (just to be sure that this is not a backend issue)?

Comment: If you’re using AWS or Rackspace, sometimes the load balancers have 2 minute timeouts.